# What 'type' is a Firebase handle for removeObserverWithHandle suppose to be in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What am I suppose to initialize the 'observer' handle as?

I currently do the following: `var handle: UInt?`, is that correct? Is it suppose to be of type `UInt` or is it suppose to be something else?

Also in the function `viewWillDisappear` i do a check for if the handle is nil prior to removing it as such

```
if handle != nil {        
    // Remove the observer
    playerRef.child(ID).removeObserver(withHandle: handle!)
}
```

By doing so does the remove Observer set the `handle` to nil?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation on detaching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#detach_listeners):

> When you add a callback block to a reference, a `FIRDatabaseHandle` is returned. These handles can be used to remove the callback block.

The handle that you pass into `removeObserver(withHandle:)` is the value that is returned when you added that observer. It is of type `DatabaseHandle`, so:

```
var refHandle: DatabaseHandle!
```

From the same documentation page comes this example of how to use it:

> ```
> refHandle = postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
>   let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
>   // ...
> })
> ```

So you'd then use `refHandle` to remove that listener:

```
postRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
```

Comment: I understand that part but what is refHandle declared as? Ex. var refHandle = <what>!?

Comment: Also a different question, do I have a observer created in an viewcontroller. The user hits the 'home' button and the app does to the background. Does the observer still keep getting real time data?! From what I can tell, the `viewDidDisappear` func does not get invoked with hitting the 'home' button. How would/should I remove the handle then?

Comment: I found the answer to the first part, I should be using `var refHandle: DatabaseHandle!`

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Database/Public/FIRDatabaseQuery.h:

```
/**
 * A FIRDatabaseHandle is used to identify listeners of Firebase Database events. These handles
 * are returned by observeEventType: and can later be passed to removeObserverWithHandle: to stop
 * receiving updates.
 */
typedef NSUInteger FIRDatabaseHandle NS_SWIFT_NAME(DatabaseHandle);
```